# Rackspace server stopped sending emails - Delivery temporarily suspended - Mailgun

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, mailgun

Rackspace server stopped sending emails

When I type 'mailq' in putty,I got follwing error :

> Delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; Server smtp.mailgun.org[ipaddress] said: 535 5.7.0 Message limit reached.

Whats the issue? How can I resolve it?

Comment: "Message limit reached"

Comment: Yes that I have read. But how can I resolve it?

Comment: Buy more credits? Why don't you just phone Rackspace for the so-called 'Fanatical support'?

Comment: Ship your load of e-mails to a 3rd party if they hold no sensitive information, such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: Mailchimp is for sending newsletter campaigns, Mandrill would be an alternative to Mailgun as a transactional email service (you are right though, it is owned by Mailchimp). They also have a limit on the freebies, sounds like a situation where the free limit is being reached and nobody wants to pay for the service.  Doesn't matter where they go, they will always hit this issue somewhere.

Comment: @McNab Ah, thanks for clearing that up for me. If they don't want to pay to e-mail their customer base, they shouldn't have customers - or change the way they interact with their customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Racker, and we see this issue quite a bit. Mailgun allows you to demo the service by sending up to 300 emails from a 'sandbox' account. Once you've hit those, you need to register a domain, and then the daily limit of 300 emails is lifted, and as a Rackspace customer you'll have a new limit of 50,000 free emails per month before you hit the next limit. After that you'll need to enter some sort of payment information and the sky's the limit.

We have a good article on [setting up Mailgun](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/4705) in the Rackspace Community, but the TL;DR is you just need to add the domain, then add a DNS TXT record to prove ownership.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer. I have already registered a domain. I have not configured domain SMTP details while sending an email. I have started sending email through Mailgun SMTP of that domain and it just started working.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :

Try to send email with sand box server and check for the following setting by:

Log in to the Cloud Control Panel by using your Rackspace Cloud account credentials.

At the top of the panel, click the Rackspace Cloud menu and then select Mailgun.
Your account synchronizes with Mailgun, and the Mailgun Control Panel opens.

(Optional) Send a test email by using the sandbox that Mailgun provides you.

Option 2:

First Check for the following settings :

Sending emails via SMTP Library

Integration with Mailgun programatically is available from languages with an SMTP library. Let's take a look at a trivial Python script that instructs Mailgun to send an email through SMTP. We will leverage the smtplib library available natively in Python.

https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/introduction-to-mailgun-email-automation

Best,